# Representing arrays in UML diagrams

Tags: uml

Just wonering how would one represent an array as a state & return from a method in a UML diagram, here is what I'm doing right now:

```
- arr : String[16]

+ getArr() : String[16]
```

is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holding that `arr` is a private non-static variable and `GetArray()` is a public non-static method,  I would say this will suffice (different teams have different ways of documenting so this is an opinion).  Some people don't include the array length in the class diagram, some do (that is your call).   If your method has paramaters, I recommended you do something like this:

```
getArray([in] param1 : dataType, [out] return1 : dataType)
```

Comment: You could also write lower/upper bounds like `String[0..15]`. Signatures are usually denoted only by type, not by name, e.g. `getArray(dataType1, dataType2):returnType`

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering & sorry for the late reply. An extra question: how would one represent an array as a parameter, for example something like arrayThings(String arr[])?